# d3.js: Multiple Series Line Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

With this code as a starting point: https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/15e4f2a49d0d25468e76ab6717cd95e7 I'm attempting to make a simple line graph with multiple data series.  Per @wasserholz suggestion, I've added a complete MVP: https://github.com/djmcmath/d3-fail-mvp

The data parsing portion seems to be working correctly, in that I'm creating a map with 5 elements, each of which is a "sailing date" and array of values associated with that date.  This is the variable named "group_by_sailing_date".

[image: Parsed / processed data]

The axes appear to be reasonable: For the X-axis, I'm taking the "since_midnight" value, pulling the extents, and formatting it as a time.  The Y-axis, similarly, is just the extents of the "margin" value.  I get this -- so far so good:

[image]

Next, I want to add some lines to my chart.  My thinking is that I iterate through the map, and for each of the map elements, I add the element as data to a series.  What I get is a gigantic "Nothing Happens" though.  No lines, no errors, just "Gosh, your data looks great, but I'm going to ignore it."

```js
//line generator?
var valueline = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.since_midnight); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d.margin); });
  
group_by_sailing_date.forEach(function (s) {
  svg_summ.append("path")
    .data(s)
    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke-width", "3px")
    .attr("d", valueline);
});
```

I feel like I'm missing something really fundamental here, but I'm drawing a complete blank (pun intended, ha ha ha).  Help?

Answer (score 1):

Following the rules of selection within d3.js (https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/) the code should look something like this:

```
svg_summ.selectAll("path")
  .data(group_by_sailing_date)
  .enter()
    .append("path")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke-width", "1px")
      .attr("d", (d) => valueline(d));
```

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly informative link.  To paraphrase for the data visualization noobs: my approach (below, which technically works) is wrong, because I'm using a javascript iterator to add each key/data pair to the chart individually.  The right way to do it is to use D3's native power to directly map the data to the chart structure.

When I try the code you've provided, though, I get "Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaN"."  I think I understand that to mean that there's no data in what I'm providing.  I remain confused, despite your helpful answer.

Comment: If you provide a minimal reproducible example of your chart, I might be able to help you.

Comment: That's fair:  https://github.com/djmcmath/d3-fail-mvp

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've made it work, but I don't know why.  I removed the .data(s) line, and changed "valueline" to "valueline(s)".  No idea why this works.  Technically, it's all good, but I'd be thrilled if someone could help me understand what this code actually means.

```
group_by_sailing_date.forEach(function (s) {
 svg_summ.append("path")
  .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke-width", "1px")
  .attr("d", valueline(s));
```

});

Comment: This is not how you should iterate over data within d3.js. Please read about selections here: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/ Especially about `data`, `enter` and `update`